# How can I UPDATE the result of a SELECT statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a table like this:

```
// notifications
+----+--------------+------+---------+------------+
| id |      event   | seen | id_user | time_stamp |
+----+--------------+------+---------+------------+
| 1  | vote         | 1    | 123     | 1464174617 |
| 2  | comment      | 1    | 456     | 1464174664 |
| 3  | vote         | 1    | 123     | 1464174725 |
| 4  | answer       | 1    | 123     | 1464174813 |
| 5  | comment      | NULL | 456     | 1464174928 |
| 6  | comment      | 1    | 123     | 1464175114 |
| 7  | vote         | NULL | 456     | 1464175317 |
| 8  | answer       | NULL | 123     | 1464175279 |
| 9  | vote         | NULL | 123     | 1464176618 |
+----+--------------+------+---------+------------+
```

And here is my query:

```
(SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp 
 FROM notifications n
 WHERE id_user = :id AND seen IS NULL
)UNION
(SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp
 FROM notification n
 WHERE id_user = :id AND seen IS NOT NULL
 LIMIT 2
)UNION 
(SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp 
 FROM notifications n
 WHERE id_user = :id 
 ORDER BY (seen IS NULL) desc, time_stamp desc
 LIMIT 15
)
ORDER BY (seen IS NULL) desc, time_stamp desc;
```

---

Now I'm trying to update matched rows from query above and set `seen = 1`, Something like this:

```
UPDATE notifications SET seen = 1 WHERE /* the result of query above */
```

How can I do that?

---

**Note:** I also use PHP and PDO to execute that SELECT query *(If it is important to know)*

```
$stm = $db->prepare(" (SELECT id, ... ");
$stm->execute( /* passing some variables */);
$stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: What other values are possible for `seen`?

Comment: `seen` accepts just two values, `NULL` *(unread messages)*, `1` *(read messages)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seen` can only be `1` or `null`. In that case, most of what you are getting from that UNION query is irrelevant. It seems to me that the end result of the update you're trying to do will be:

```
UPDATE notifications SET seen = 1 WHERE id_user = :id AND seen IS NULL
```

Anything else will be updating something that's already `1` to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use where in clause  .. but in this case you need ond the id

```
    UPDATE notifications SET seen = 1 WHERE id in (
    (SELECT id
     FROM notifications n
     WHERE id_user = :id AND seen IS NULL
    )UNION
    (SELECT id
     FROM notification n
     WHERE id_user = :id AND seen IS NOT NULL
     LIMIT 2
    )UNION 
    (SELECT id
     FROM notifications n
     WHERE id_user = :id 
     ORDER BY (seen IS NULL) desc, time_stamp desc
     LIMIT 15
    ))
```

Comment: Well to be honest I knew that. But I thought there is a more simple solution. tnx anyway

Comment: I mean can I store the number of ids into a PHP variable and use it in `update` statement? Something like this `UPDATE . . . WHERE id IN (".$ids.") `

Comment: Yes you can use  a formatted string like in your comment  but also also an array  for the in clause  ... there some suggestion on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in MySQL, use `JOIN`:

```
update notifications n join
       (select id
        from ((SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp 
               FROM notifications n
               WHERE id_user = :id AND seen IS NULL
              ) UNION
              (SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp
               FROM notification n
               WHERE id_user = :id AND seen IS NOT NULL
               LIMIT 2
              ) UNION 
              (SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp 
               FROM notifications n
               WHERE id_user = :id 
               ORDER BY (seen IS NULL) desc, time_stamp desc
               LIMIT 15
              )) n
       ) nids
       on n.id = nids.id
    set seen = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly modify your query to use as subquery for update statement:

```
UPDATE notifications SET seen = 1 WHERE id in (
    (SELECT id
     FROM notifications n
     WHERE id_user = :id AND seen IS NULL
    )UNION
    (SELECT id
     FROM notification n
     WHERE id_user = :id AND seen IS NOT NULL
     LIMIT 2
    )UNION 
    (SELECT id
     FROM notifications n
     WHERE id_user = :id 
     ORDER BY (seen IS NULL) desc, time_stamp desc
     LIMIT 15
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have retrieved all applicable ID's into your application.  All you need to do is then is

```
UPDATE notifications
SET seen = 1
WHERE id IN (?,?,?)
```

where the `?` are replaced by the id values.

Comment: That's correct, Just may you please show me how can I extract all ID's from `$result = $stm->fetchAll();` and use it into that `UPDATE` statement?